# Python: How to keep track of how a list was sorted?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Given a list `l0` of numbers in arbitrary order that may contain duplicates, how to have it sorted to `l_s` while keeping track of ***how*** `l0` was sorted, so that the original `l0_order` can be reproduced later on (`l_in_l0_order`)?

The point is to apply `l0_order` to ***another*** list `l` that is in `l_s` order to retrieve a list `l_in_l0_order` ordered according to `l0`.

What I use so far is

```py
l0 = [1, 7, 3, 12, 12, 4]
ls = sorted(l0)
# ls
# [1, 3, 4, 7, 12, 12]

l0_order = [ls.index(v) for v in l0]
l_in_l0_order = [ls[i] for i in l0_order]
# l_in_l0_order
# [1, 7, 3, 12, 12, 4]
```

- is there a more clever way to do this? For large lists, this make a lot of calls to `index`

Note: for a list with elements with equal value but different `id`, the method above can produce invalid results because `index` (afaik) compares values, not ids. I do not require that behavior (order of `id`), but it might be of relevance for a general solution.

Comment: Is numpy not an option? You could just go with `argsort` if performance is an issue

Comment: Downvoting is fine - but please leave a comment ***why*** to make room for improvement. Otherwise, this is just *not helpful*. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system will fail if you have items in `l0` that are equal but not identical. Furthermore, the use of `.index` on every member is unnecessary bloat, O(N^2). In these kinds of circumstances, you want to sort the *keys*, and *then* look up the elements, rather than sort the elements and look up the keys as you did. For one thing, looking up elements by key is fast; for another, there is no ambiguity which element you're fetching.

```
order = sorted(list(range(len(l0))), key=lambda i: l0[i])
l1 = [l0[i] for i in order]
```

As said in comments, `numpy.argsort` does the same thing.

To reverse the permutation, you can repeat the same process on `order`:

```
inverse_order = sorted(order, key=lambda i: order[i])
l0_again = [l1[i] for i in inverse_order]
```

Obviously, you can use the same process to put another list that is in `l1` order back into `l0` order:

```
ls_in_l0_order = [ls[i] for i in inverse_order]
```